# Date object not returning a valid date

Tags: javascript, date, object

I am trying to get a date and return the age of a user using the difference. I have looked at some similar questions on here and while helpful they haven't fully solved my problem. My date constant keeps returning a not valid date, so I can't use it to compare to the current time to get an age.

```
    <div id="container">
        <form id="form">
            <label for="fname">First name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
            <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br>
            <label for="userId">User ID:</label>
            <input type="text" name="userId" id="userId" required><br>
            <label for="userBirthday">Birthday</label>
            <input type="date" id="date" name="userBirthday"><br>
            <button type="submit" id="submit">Accept</button>
        </form>
        <div id="displayWindow"></div>
    </div>
```

```
<script>
        const container = document.getElementById("container")
        const displayW = document.getElementById("displayWindow")
        const uid = document.getElementById("userId")
        const fname = document.getElementById("fname")
        const lname = document.getElementById("lname")
        let birthday = document.querySelector("input[type='date']").value
        let birthVal = new Date(birthday);
        const submit = document.getElementById("submit")
        const form = document.getElementById("form")
        const currentDate = Date.now();

        function inputValidation() {
            let lowerCase = /[a-z]/g
            let upperCase = /[A-Z]/g
            let userNum = /[0-9]/g
            let hasErrors = false
            if (uid.value.length < 7 || uid.value.length > 12) {
                alert("User ID must be between eight and twelve characters")
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            if (!(uid.value.match(lowerCase)) || !(uid.value.match(upperCase))) {
                alert("User ID must contain at least one lowercase and uppercase letter")
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            if (!(uid.value.match(userNum))) {
                alert("User ID must contain at least one number")
                event.preventDefault();
            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
            }

        };
        function dateDiff() {
            const difference = currentDate - birthVal;
            const differenceInDays = Math.round(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            if (differenceInDays > 6574) {
                displayW.innerHTML = `You are probably not old enough to take this class!`;
            } else {
                displayW.innerHTML = `fname lname you have been breathing for ${differenceInDays} days!`;
            }
        }
        form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
            inputValidation();
            dateDiff();
        });

    </script>
```

I tried using different methods (Date.parse(), getTime(), .value, toUTCString(), toISOString), but none of those would return a string or a number. Just Invalid Date. I thought it might be something wrong with the browser, but couldn't find any issue (Using Chrome). Tried changing variables from const to let. I tried moving around variables to see if the function scope had anything to do with it. Thank you to anyone who shares their time and knowledge to this noob.

Comment: You just need to move `birthVal = new Date(birthday);` inside the event handler so it picks up the current value, not the value when the page loads.

Answer (score 2):

The `birthday` value will always be the initial value which is empty. Get the date value in the `dateDiff` function before doing your calculation

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container")
const displayW = document.getElementById("displayWindow")
const uid = document.getElementById("userId")
const fname = document.getElementById("fname")
const lname = document.getElementById("lname")
const submit = document.getElementById("submit")
const form = document.getElementById("form")
const currentDate = Date.now();

function inputValidation() {
    let lowerCase = /[a-z]/g
    let upperCase = /[A-Z]/g
    let userNum = /[0-9]/g
    let hasErrors = false

    if (uid.value.length < 7 || uid.value.length > 12) {
        alert("User ID must be between eight and twelve characters")
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if (!(uid.value.match(lowerCase)) || !(uid.value.match(upperCase))) {
        alert("User ID must contain at least one lowercase and uppercase letter")
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if (!(uid.value.match(userNum))) {
        alert("User ID must contain at least one number")
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

};
function dateDiff() {
    let birthday = document.querySelector("input[type='date']").value
    let birthVal = new Date(birthday);
    const difference = currentDate - birthVal;
    const differenceInDays = Math.round(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    if (differenceInDays > 6574) {
        displayW.innerHTML = `You are probably not old enough to take this class!`;
    } else {
        displayW.innerHTML = `fname lname you have been breathing for ${differenceInDays} days!`;
    }
}
form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    inputValidation();
    dateDiff();
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <form id="form">
        <label for="fname">First name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
        <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br>
        <label for="userId">User ID:</label>
        <input type="text" name="userId" id="userId" required><br>
        <label for="userBirthday">Birthday</label>
        <input type="date" id="date" name="userBirthday"><br>
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Accept</button>
    </form>
    <div id="displayWindow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was thinking it had something to do with the order of things, but now that you've actually explained it in a very palatable way, it actually makes sense! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you shuold use event listeneres on inputs. you can't get their values when there is no value (there is just empty string). try to log both birthDay and birthVal, you can see birthDay is empty string ("") which is not a valid date for new Date(); you should use proper event listeners and proper event handlers on them to catch user inputs and do whatever you want with them. try to learn more about javascript basic concepts like (event listeners) and then use them. good luck :);

Comment: No need for event listeners "on inputs" - OP is already correctly using an event listener  on `submit`.  Just needs to (re)initialise `birthVal` at the time of use rather than on startup.